# Kinesis Data Firehose source `Direct PUT` vs `Kinesis Data Stream`

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-kinesis

When I create Kinesis Data Firehose stream, there are 2 options for the Source,

- Direct PUT or other sources
- Kinesis Data Stream

What are the advantage and disadvantage of these options?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

They serve different purposes. But if your aim is only to inject records for storing (and transforming optionally) in S3, Redshift or ElasticSearch, then the **main difference   is simplicity**.

**Direct PUT or other sources**

Allows for direct "manual" injection of records into `firehose`. For the ingestion, you or your application have to use [put-record](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/firehose/put-record.html) or [put-record-batch](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/firehose/put-record-batch.html).

These api calls are **very simple and straightforward** to use, in a sense you don't need to manage records partitioning. Because you just provide them with `firehose` name and the record(s) to be written. Nothing else is reacquired.

Also `firehose` is basically serverless, thus you do not need to manage its scaling or provision its throughput. Its all done **automatically** for you.

However, `firehose` is **not completely "real-time"**. Due to its timeout and buffering your records always get delayed.

**Kinesis Data Stream**

If you front your `firehose` with `kinesis stream`, then you have to inject  records to the stream. For that you use [put-record](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/kinesis/put-record.html) and  or [put-records](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/kinesis/put-records.html). If you look at these api calls, they are **more complicated** as you have to manage `key partitioning` yourself. You have to do it correctly, as otherwise you end up with hot/cold shards and worries how to fix that.

Also `data streams` are not serverless in a sense that they **do not autoscale**. You have to manage their throughput yourself. This means that you have to calculate and provision the number of shards you require. If you do it incorrectly, you will have issues.

**Conclusions**

Choose direct put to `firehose` if you **only aim at storing** (transforming) your records in supported storage destinations.

Choose to use kinesis data stream in front of `firehose` if you require not only storing, but also doing **other things** with your records in **real-time**. This is because you can have other stream consumers than `firehose` which do require real-time data.

Comment: `PutRecordsBatch` is not "very simple and straightforward": it actually has a failure mode in which some records are rejected while others are accepted, and a program that writes to it must be prepared for that situation (it's the same with Kinesis streams, btw).

Comment: @Parsifal Thanks, but I was referring to no need to worry about partitioning or sequence numbers.  I will update the answer.

Comment: Kinesis Data Streams now supports an [on-demand](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/amazon-kinesis-data-streams-on-demand-stream-data-at-scale-without-managing-capacity/) mode to auto scale the stream. On-demand removes some of the complications of using a stream but doesn't really change your conclusion.

Answer (score 2):

The primary difference (assuming that you're not attaching anything else to the stream) is that you need a support ticket to scale Firehose.

Per the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/firehose/latest/dev/limits.html):

> When Direct PUT is configured as the data source, each Kinesis Data Firehose delivery stream provides the following combined quota for PutRecord and PutRecordBatch requests:
>
> - For US East (N. Virginia), US West (Oregon), and Europe (Ireland): 5,000 records/second, 2,000 requests/second, and 5 MiB/second.
> - For US East (Ohio), US West (N. California), AWS GovCloud (US-East), AWS GovCloud (US-West), Asia Pacific (Hong Kong), Asia Pacific (Mumbai), Asia Pacific (Seoul), Asia Pacific (Singapore), Asia Pacific (Sydney), Asia Pacific (Tokyo), Canada (Central), Europe (Frankfurt), Europe (London), Europe (Paris), Europe (Stockholm), Middle East (Bahrain), and South America (São Paulo): 1,000 records/second, 1,000 requests/second, and 1 MiB/second.
>
> To request an increase in quota, use the Amazon Kinesis Data Firehose Limits form.

Kinesis streams, by comparison, let you control scaling based on the number of shards: 1,000 records per second or 1 MB/second ingest per shard. If you discover that you need more capacity, you can easily increase the number of shards.

Another difference is that Firehose only retains records for 24 hours if the destination is unavailable, while a Kinesis stream can be configured to retain records for up to a week.

For a robust architecture, I recommend using a combination of Kinesis streams for ingest, and Firehose for batching and writing to the destination.